# epstopdf does not find (or generate) pdf file

Tags: epstopdf

I have an error while trying to use epstopdf package. 
This is my code

```
\documentclass[11pt,oneside,a4paper,onecolumn]{article}

\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{pstricks}
\usepackage{epsfig}
\usepackage{pst-grad} % For gradients
\usepackage{pst-plot} % For axes

% For using eps files
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\epstopdfsetup{outdir=./}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[h!]
  \centering
    \includegraphics[width=0.1\textwidth]{./apple2.eps}
    \caption{Apple}                                                             
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

This is the error message:

```
Package epstopdf Warning: Shell escape feature is not enabled.

(/usr/share/texmf-texlive/tex/latex/latexconfig/epstopdf-sys.cfg))) (./fig.aux)
(/usr/share/texmf-texlive/tex/context/base/supp-pdf.mkii
[Loading MPS to PDF converter (version 2006.09.02).]
)

! Package pdftex.def Error: File `./apple2-eps-converted-to.pdf' not found.

See the pdftex.def package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.15 ...raphics[width=0.1\textwidth]{./apple2.eps}

?
```

Do you know how to fix it?

Comment: You need to enable `--shell-escape`. So this either from the command line, or within your editor.

Comment: When using PSTricks( `\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{pstricks}`) go with `latex-->dvips-->ps2pdf` or `xelatex` compilation route (both support for inclusion of `.eps` figures normally), and hence no need for extra packages `\usepackage{epstopdf}` plus `-shell-escape` enabled as @Werner suggested. Note: replace `\usepackage{epsfig} (obsolete)` with `\usepackage{graphicx}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When using PSTricks package `\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{pstricks}` go with

`latex-->dvips-->ps2pdf` 
or 
`xelatex` compilation route 
(both support for inclusion of .eps figures normally). With both compilation routes, there is no need for extra packages `\usepackage{epstopdf}` plus `-shell-escape` enabled as @Werner suggested.

Note: replace obsolete `\usepackage{epsfig}` with `\usepackage{graphicx}`

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem and solved it by adding `\include{graphicx}` before `\include{epstopdf}`.